# PHP - send email via phpMailer from another server

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

i try to send email from **server 2** with email that opened in direct admin at **server 1**

i tried like this:

```
public function send() {
    $mail             = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = "mail.server1.com"; // SMTP server
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = true;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = "name@server1.com";
    $mail->Password   = "pass";
    $mail->SetFrom('name@server1.com', 'name');
    $mail->AddReplyTo("name@server1.com","name");
    $mail->Subject    = $this->subj;
    $mail->MsgHTML($this->msg);
    $address = $this->mailTo;
    $address = explode(',', $address);
    foreach($address as $k=>$v) {
        $mail->AddAddress($v);
    }
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Send();
}
```

this function i run at server2.com.

i got a error:

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
<br />SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

what can i do?

Comment: Obviously, you cannot connect to the SMTP server. Have you checked all possible configuration variables? What happens if you set `$mail->SMTPDebug` to a numeric value like documented at https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/SMTP-Debugging

Comment: define your port. As well as check whether server2 can connect to server1 on port, on which you going to send email. Port can be generally 25,2525,587. Use `telnet mail.server1.com 25` to check.

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the parameters:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure // can be 'tls' or 'ssl'
$mail->Port // can be '587' to TLS or '465' to SSL
```

Comment: $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
  $mail->Port = 587;
and
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
  $mail->Port = 465;


same timeout.

Comment: Try gmail account to see if the problem is on the code or the internet (firewall, ...)

Comment: same code worked in server2 ... its same host company

Comment: Try see if the smtp is alive and the port is listening on 587 on server1

Comment: when i write telnet mail.server1.com 587 or telnet mail.server1.com 25
i got
220 workd.serverhosting.com ESMTP Exim 4.90_1 Sat, 10 Mar 2018 15:07:08 -0500